# Docker compose wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

This is my docker-compose.yml so far:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80

  net: "bridge"
  dns:
    - 8.8.8.8
    - 4.4.4.4

db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: biersaufen
```

Is there a way to directly install wordpress plugins? (Directly means that i can install it via the docker-compose.yml)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but not directly via the docker-compose file.

You need to use the "build" section of the docker compose and have a Dockerfile that will install the modules for you. That way when you run `docker-compose` on your directory, it will first build the image with the plugins and use that image to start the stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot - really helpful - can you provide a little example ;) Would be nice!

Comment: I am no wordpress expert, not really sure how the plugin system works. But once you figure it out, just put all the steps in your Dockerfile :)